# Checking for certain data across servers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

How can I find a certain data from different MySQL servers? I have no problem finding from one server but I have to switch to another to find another. All the servers have the same database because the data is too large and they are partitioned out to different servers. Is there an easier way to do this that will not impose a heavy load on the servers?

This is the query I need to run on each server. Then I would count how many rows satisfy this condition.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE userID = 'some_value' AND user_level = 3
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to only count the rows, or you need all the records as well?

Comment: @LajosArpad - Actually I would like to get the count if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following query on each database server:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Table1
WHERE userID = 'some_value' AND user_level = 3
```

and calculate the sum of the results. Remember that this way the database server will only send some numbers as a result of the request, not the whole selection, which might consist of millions of records. So it drastically reduces the needed memory and time to perform the selection described here than to return all the records and then count them, your solution was an overkill.